# Listing all emails on a shared mailbox with attachments name

Tags: powershell, outlook

I have created a very simple powershell script to collect some basic information about all the emails on a shared mailbox folder.

```
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type] 
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$Inbox = $namespace.pickfolder()
$Inbox.items | Select-Object -Property Categories, Attachments, Subject, ReceivedTime
```

This is working as expected, printing a table which can be exported as CSV, but the `Attachments` property just print `System.__ComObject`. So, I need to replace the "Attachments" column with a list of the attachments names (`$_.Attachments::DisplayName`)

I tried to iterate the results to fix this, with something like:

```
$Inbox.items | Select-Object -Property Categories, Attachments, 
Subject, ReceivedTime | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.Attachments::DisplayName}
```

But this prints only the attachment information and not the rest of the data. Also, adding all the fields between {} cause powershell to print one field per line, so it can't be exported as CSV.

Can you help me to replace the Attachments column properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the last line:

```
$Inbox.items |Select-Object -Property Categories,Subject,   
ReceivedTime,@{name="Attachments";expression={$_.Attachments|%{$_.DisplayName}}}
```

you can then pipe it to `| ft -wrap` to "expand" the Attachments column.