# Powershell - outlook get inbox shared mailbox

Tags: powershell, outlook

i try get items inbox from shared mailbox, but I get blank. Why? Can I help me, please? Thank you

```
$class = @"
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
public class MyOL{
public MAPIFolder GetInbox(string userName){
Application oOutlook = new Application();
NameSpace oNs = oOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Recipient oRep = oNs.CreateRecipient(userName);
MAPIFolder inbox = oNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(oRep, OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
return inbox;
}
}
"@
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Add-Type $class -ReferencedAssemblies Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
$MyOL = New-Object MyOL
$email = $MyOL.GetInbox('test@email.com')
```

Comment: Unless you have permissions to reach into another users mailbox, you can't. Why are you using a custom class for something that is natively possible with .Net namespaces. See an example here (the example is for normal mailbox access) - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/outlook-email-automation-with-powershell/ --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940851/listing-all-emails-on-a-shared-mailbox-with-attachments-name ---

Comment: "I get blank"? Do you mean you get an error? What is it?

Comment: I have permissions another mailbox . In Outlook, I can read e-mails from this inbox and also send e-mails from this inbox. I see my email in Outlook as follows - https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/43225f7c-dc4c-476e-8ba1-d6fccd4e56c0.png .