Extract 'has attachment' from email messages
The script below gives me a list of items in an email mailbox, along with the associated metadata. The script works, but does not indicate whether an email has an attachment.  How do I go about getting this?
I tried adding hasAttachment to the line of properties in the script below, which returned completely blank values.  I also tried Attachments which returned System.__ComObject for every item. Then I tried Attachments.DisplayName; Attachments[1].DisplayName; Attachments[1].FileName - as described here.  None worked.
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

function Get-MailFromOutlookFolder
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Object] $ParentFolder
    )

    $items = @()

    foreach ($folder in $ParentFolder.Folders)
    {
        foreach ($item in ($folder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Items"))
        { 
            if ($item.Class -eq 43)
            {
                # process email
                $items += $item | Select-Object -Property "ConversationTopic", "ReceivedTime", "Body", "SenderName", "HasAttachment","SenderEmailAddress", @{ "Label" = "Folder"; "Expression" = { $_.Parent.Name } }
            }
        }

        # process (sub)folder items
        $items += Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $folder
    }

    return $items    
}

$outlook     = New-Object -Com "Outlook.Application"
$mapi        = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$mailboxRoot = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent
$results = Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $mailboxRoot
$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Blah\email.csv"

I replaced the middle line with $items += $item | Select-Object -Property "*" = { $_.Parent.Name }  and got a list of possible properties (please see below) but the only relevant one is Attachments - and I already know that doesn't work.
Application, Class, Session, Parent, Actions, Attachments, BillingInformation, Body, Categories, Companies, ConversationIndex, ConversationTopic, CreationTime, EntryID, FormDescription, GetInspector, Importance, LastModificationTime, MAPIOBJECT, MessageClass, Mileage, NoAging, OutlookInternalVersion, OutlookVersion, Saved, Sensitivity, Size, Subject, UnRead, UserProperties, AlternateRecipientAllowed, AutoForwarded, BCC, CC, DeferredDeliveryTime, DeleteAfterSubmit, ExpiryTime, FlagDueBy, FlagRequest, FlagStatus, HTMLBody, OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested, ReadReceiptRequested, ReceivedByEntryID, ReceivedByName, ReceivedOnBehalfOfEntryID, ReceivedOnBehalfOfName, ReceivedTime, RecipientReassignmentProhibited, Recipients, ReminderOverrideDefault, ReminderPlaySound, ReminderSet, ReminderSoundFile, ReminderTime, RemoteStatus, ReplyRecipientNames, ReplyRecipients, SaveSentMessageFolder, SenderName, Sent, SentOn, SentOnBehalfOfName, Submitted, To, VotingOptions, VotingResponse, Links, ItemProperties, BodyFormat, DownloadState, InternetCodepage, MarkForDownload, IsConflict, IsIPFax, FlagIcon, HasCoverSheet, AutoResolvedWinner, Conflicts, SenderEmailAddress, SenderEmailType, EnableSharedAttachments, Permission, PermissionService, PropertyAccessor, SendUsingAccount, TaskSubject, TaskDueDate, TaskStartDate, TaskCompletedDate, ToDoTaskOrdinal, IsMarkedAsTask, ConversationID, Sender, PermissionTemplateGuid, RTFBody, RetentionPolicyName, RetentionExpirationDate

Is it possible that I have to open up the com.object and if yes, how do I do that?
Updated script - Reflecting @Dmitry Streblechenko's suggestion to use PR_HASATTACH
function Get-MailFromOutlookFolder
{

    foreach ($item in ($folder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Items"))
    { 
        if ($item.Class -eq 43)
        {
            # Retrieve the PR_HASATTACH MAPI property
            $hasAttach = $item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B")
        
            # process email
            $items += $item | Select-Object -Property "ConversationTopic", "ReceivedTime", "Body", "SenderName", "HasAttachment", "SenderEmailAddress", @{ "Label" = "Folder"; "Expression" = { $_.Parent.Name } }, @{ "Label" = "HasAttachment"; "Expression" = { $hasAttach} }
        
        }
    }
 }

$outlook     = New-Object -Com "Outlook.Application"
$mapi        = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
$mailboxRoot = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent
$results = Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $mailboxRoot
$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Bleh\email.csv"

PS. The nesting is necessary to capture subfolder contents.

You will need to retrieve PR_HASATTACH (DASL name "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B") MAPI property using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty
foreach ($item in ($folder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Items"))
{ 
    if ($item.Class -eq 43)
    {
        # Retrieve the PR_HASATTACH MAPI property
        $hasAttach = $item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B")
        
        # process email
        $items += $item | Select-Object -Property "ConversationTopic", "ReceivedTime", "Body", "SenderName", "HasAttachment", "SenderEmailAddress", @{ "Label" = "Folder"; "Expression" = { $_.Parent.Name } }, @{ "Label" = "HasAttachment"; "Expression" = { $hasAttach} }
    }
}

Note that looping through all items in a folder is a pretty bad idea - either restrict the number of the matching items using Items.Restrict or Items.Find/FindNext or (if you indeed need to read all items in a folder) retrieve the properties using from multiple items using MAPITable.GetTable - call Columns.Add first to specify PR_HASATTACH and other properties.

Thank you for helping @Dmitry Streblechenko.  If you have the time, would you be willing to provide me with a script that incorporates PR_HASATTACH?  I tried adding it into my script, but the resulting column was blank.

Please show your code

See the updated answer above

I got the error You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.  I put https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B into my web browser and it says the resource does not exist.@Dmitry Streblechenko

Which line produces the error? The DALS name is not a link, it is property name.

The line is `At line:41 char:12

$results = Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $mailboxRoot`


the error code isn't that useful because it refers to the whole function.  I took out $hasAttach = $item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1B000B") and the error code went away.

I don't know, I am not really a PS user. Is $item.PropertyAccessor null?

I think $hasAttach is null.  Also: thank you for trying - it was helpful to see how you would approach the problem.

PR_HAS_ATTACH is always available - I have not seen a single store kind that does not expose it. Can you see it in OutlookSpy (click IMessage button)?

Found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21940851/listing-all-emails-on-a-shared-mailbox-with-attachments-name

You need to add @{name="Attachments";expression={$_.Attachments|%{$_.DisplayName}}}
Full script below:
Set-StrictMode -Version "Latest"
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

function Get-MailFromOutlookFolder
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param 
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [Object] $ParentFolder
    )

    $items = @()

    foreach ($folder in $ParentFolder.Folders)
    {
        foreach ($item in ($folder | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "Items"))
        { 
            if ($item.Class -eq 43)
            {
                # process email
                $PR_SMTP_ADDRESS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"
                #$smtpAddress = $item.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty($PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
                $items += $item | Select-Object -Property "ConversationTopic", "ReceivedTime", "Body", "SenderName", "ReceivedByName", "BCC", "CC","Size", "SenderEmailAddress", @{ "Label" = "Folder"; "Expression" = { $_.Parent.Name } }, @{name="Attachments";expression={$_.Attachments|%{$_.DisplayName}}}
            }
        }

        # process (sub)folder items
        $items += Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $folder
    }

    return $items    
}

$outlook     = New-Object -Com "Outlook.Application"
$mapi        = $outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
#$mailboxRoot = $mapi.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox).Parent
#if you want to change the inbox to a shared inbox, comment out the below, and play with numbers
$mailboxRoot = $mapi.Folders.Item(8)
$results = Get-MailFromOutlookFolder -ParentFolder $mailboxRoot
$results | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Bleh\email.csv"

